# Core Data CloudKit error: must specify an inverse relationship

Tags: core-data, cloudkit, xcode11, swift5

I'm receiving an error connected with CloudKit when I made my Core Data Model.

Here's my model:

[image]

The errors:

> Entity.attribute must specify an inverse relationship
>
> Entity.attribute must not be ordered

[image: 11]

Is my Core Data model connected properly and how can I fix the errors?

Answer (score 2):

Would you just do what CloudKit asked you?

Eg. for

> "Sold.toClient must specify an inverse relationship"

1. go to grid-style Editor for *Clients* entity
2. in Relationships section add relationship named, say, *toSold*
3. select in Destination column *Sold* from popup, and in Inverse column *toClient* from popup.

Do some for other entities. CloudKit has own requirements for data model, so to integrate you must follow them even though locally your data model works.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the Apple Documentation titled “[Creating a Core Data Model for CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/creating_a_core_data_model_for_cloudkit#3191035)”...

Specifically under the subheading “Design a CloudKit-Compatible Core Data Model”.

> Relationships
>
> All relationships must be optional. Due to operation
> size limitations, relationship changes may not be saved atomically.
> **All relationships must have an inverse, in case the records
> synchronize out of order.** (In a Core Data model, an inverse is
> strongly recommended but not required.)

You’ll need to modify your object graph to include an inverse for each of your relationships.

With reference to the image you’ve provided, once you’ve completed that task, you’ll see an arrow at either end of the connecting “relationship” lines.

For a “to-many” relationship, you’ll see double chevron (**>>**) and for a “to-one” relationship you’ll see a single chevron (**>**).